# Binding between two xaml windows

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following slider:

```
<Slider x:Name="uiScaleSlider" Value="1" Minimum="0.5" Maximum="1.5" />
```

Which affects a scale transformation:

```
 <ScaleTransform  
      CenterX="0" 
      CenterY="0" 
      ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=uiScaleSlider,Path=Value}"  
      ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=uiScaleSlider,Path=Value}" />
```

However they each are on seperate windows (i.e the slider is on an 'options' screen and the scaletransform is on the main window).

How do I bind the two windows so the slider and scaletransform can connect and therefore operate?

Comment: Do you have view models for this ?

Comment: You should have one viewmodel that contains the actual value, and then both views bind to the same viewmodel and present the value accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage to have `App` variable, which can be shared among the views. I'm not sure its cleaner way. But i have something similar in the production.

**In you App.xaml.cs**

Create your model for the binding.

```
private static int _minimumValue;
public static int MinimumValue
 {
        get
        {
            return _minimumValue;
        }
        set
        {
            _minimumValue = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedStatic("MinimumValue");
        }
}
```

**Option Screen Xaml should look like this**

```
<Slider x:Name="uiScaleSlider" Value="1" 
        Minimum={Binding MinimumValue, Source="{x:Static Application.Current}" />
```

**MainWindow.Xaml**

```
<ScaleTransform  
  CenterX="0" 
  CenterY="0" 
  ScaleX={Binding MinimumValue, Source="{x:Static Application.Current}" />
```

Comment: Glad it helped, If you find any better solution please let me know